# Scala: Make covariant type invariant

Tags: scala, covariance, contravariance

I would like to achieve the following functionality:

```
case class ValidatorClean[+A](apply: A => A)

implicit val traversableValidatorClean = ValidatorClean[Traversable[String]](_.map(_.trim))
```

so that `traversableValidatorClean` gets picked whenever a `ValidatorClean[Seq[String]]` or `ValidatorClean[List[String]]` is needed, for example.

However, this doesn't compile, with the error

```
covariant type A occurs in contravariant position in type => A => A of value apply
```

I understand that a function is contravariant in its input and covariant in its output, but I want `A` to behave invariantly in `apply`. That is, the function in `apply` will always return the exact same type as its input.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Anybody seen a question about going the other way (making an invariant covariant)?

Comment: @combinatorist `type G[+T] = F[_ <: T]`, `type G[-T] = F[_ >: T]` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75035824/in-scala3-if-generic-type-arguments-is-mapped-to-dependent-type-how-are-cova

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense for `ValidatorClean` to be covariant.

Lets say you have:

```
abstract class Animal

object Animal {
    def validate[A <: Animal : ValidatorClean](animal: A): Animal =
        implicitly[ValidatorClean[A]].apply(animal)
}

class Cat {
    def canMeow: Boolean = ???
}

class Dog {
    def canBark: Boolean = ???
}
```

By making `ValidatorClean` covariant, you're saying that `ValidatorClean[Dog]` is a sub-type of `ValidatorClean[Animal]`, which means that if you need a `ValidatorClean[Animal]`, you will also accept a `ValidatorClean[Dog]` or `ValidatorClean[Cat]` for that matter.

So let's suppose we have an `Animal`, but we don't know it's sub-type.

```
 val unknown: Animal = new Dog // perhaps the Animal really came from a List
```

Now I write:

```
Animal.validate(unknown)
```

What happens? If there is an implicit `ValidatorClean[Dog]` available, `validate` will gladly accept it. Perhaps it looks like:

```
implicit validateDog = ValidatorClean[Dog](dog => if (dog.canBark) dog else ???)
```

But how can this function that accepts a `Dog` and calls `canBark` also process an arbitrary `Animal`? It can't.

Similarly, a `ValidatorClean[Traversable[String]]` would also resolve for a `ValidatorClean[Any]`, even though `Any` does not have a `map` method, so it cannot work.

Comment: Hey @mk thank you for your answer. I think I got covariance and contravariance mixed up. I am striving for `case class ValidatorClean[-A](apply: A => A)` then, so that a `ValidatorClean[Dog]` accepts a `ValidatorClean[Animal]`. This doesn't compile either, since `A` is also covariant in the function. (Also, I accept suggestions as to whether edit the original question, make a new one, or leave it just as it is; i want to honor your answer).

Comment: It doesn't work if it's contravariant either. If you have a `ValidatorClean[Animal]` (which holds a function `Animal => Animal`) and you try to use it as a `ValidatorClean[Dog]` (which holds a function `Dog => Dog`, then somehow the `ValidatorClean[Animal]` needs to know how to produce a `Dog`.

Comment: I see. I still think there should be a way of providing a function that applies to `A` or any of its subtypes and produce another exact `A` (that's why I mentioned making it invariant in the subject). Like in the example, where `_.map(_.trim)` applies to `Traversable[String]` or any of its subclasses, and given a `Seq[String]` produces another `Seq[String]`, given a `List[String]` produces a `List[String]`, etc.

Comment: @rpiaggio You can have `case class ValidatorClean[+A](apply: (_ <: A) => A)` or `case class ValidatorClean[+A, B <: A](apply: B => A)` or `case class ValidatorClean[+A, -B <: A](apply: B => A)`