# Java Type Variance Too Permissive?

Tags: java, scala, generics, variance

In a modern functional language like Scala, type variance is inherent in the type. Here's e.g. Scala's `Function1`:

```
trait Function1[-T1, +R] { ... }
```

contravariant in parameter type and covariant in return type. And here's java's counterpart:

```
interface Function<T,R> { ... }
```

Now, to express variance relationship, the "wildcard capture" special syntax is used. For example, the stream's `map` function is declared as

```
<R> Stream<T> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper);
```

Here, Java shifts the declaration of variance relationship from the type itself to its use as a param in some method signature.

Here's my question. Would I be amiss to say that there cannot be any legitimate usages of `Function<T,R>` that are not contravariant in T and covariant in R? In other words, does Java's way offer useful extra flexibility not found in Scala, or is it just a lot of repetitive unwieldy boilerplate?

Comment: Scala was implemented after Java; why would you expect extra flexibility in the earlier language? In fact, Java generics were implemented as compile time type safety and are erased at runtime (to be fair, a bridge method is also generated and inserted).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Bridge methods are only generated in fairly special circumstances (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html), though there are also plenty of other situations where generics aren't fully erased (see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/280169/if-scala-runs-on-the-jvm-how-can-scala-do-things-that-java-seemingly-cannot/280189#280189).

Comment: @IgorUrisman In Scala you could also have invariant `trait Function[T, R]` and declare variance at a call site `type VarFunction[-T, +R] = Function[_ >: T, _ <: R]` like in Java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75035824/in-scala3-if-generic-type-arguments-is-mapped-to-dependent-type-how-are-cova So there is no extra flexibility in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Scala supports both declaration and use site variance. Specifically, you can [specify bounded wildcards just like in Java](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/changed-features/wildcards.html).

This already hints that declaration site variance can not replace use site variance in all cases. The reason is that a declaration can only be variant if it is variant in all possible uses. If some uses are variant, but other uses are not, we can't use declaration site variance, but we can use use site variance.

For instance, class `Array[A]` can not be declared variant, but the method [appendedAll from ArrayOps](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/collection/ArrayOps.html) can employ use site variance

```
def appendedAll[B >: A](suffix: Array[_ <: B])(implicit arg0: ClassTag[B]): Array[B]
```

since it uses covariant methods of `suffix`.

Answer (score 4):

For `Function` specifically, no. [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) defines exactly one abstract method, `apply`, which uses `T` contravariantly and `R` covariantly. But `Function` isn't what they had in mind when they designed that feature.

When the Java devs designed call-site variance, they were imagining classes that had *both* covariant and contravariant uses. For instance, in principle, the `E` in `List<E>` must be invariant. It appears in covariant position in [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) and in contravariant position in [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-).

So the rationale was this. Suppose we have a type hierarchy `X <= Y <= Z`. That is, `X` is a class that subclasses `Y`, and `Y` in turn subclasses `Z`. A `List<Y>` can do anything with type `Y`. It can have `Y`s added to the end, and a user can retrieve elements of type `Y` from it. But it can never be a `List<Z>` or a `List<X>`, since adding to a `List<X>` would be unsound, and so would retrieving as a `List<Z>`.

But we can express our intention. `List<? extends Y>` is a type we can only ever read from. It actually *can* take a `List<Z>` under the hood, since a list of `Z` elements is genuinely still (at least for covariant methods) a list of `Y` elements. We can get elements from this list, but we can't add to the end of it, since we said we're using the type argument in covariant position but `add` uses the type argument contravariantly. Essentially, `List<? extends Y>` is a smaller interface that includes some of the methods from the *actual* interface `List`.

The same is true of `List<? super Y>`. We can't read from it, since we don't know that every element is of type `Y`. But we can add to it, since we know that the list at least *supports* elements of type `Y`. We can use all of the contravariant methods, like `add`, but none of the covariant ones.

For a type like `List` that uses its type arguments in different ways, the call-site variance makes some amount of sense. For a special-purpose interface like `Function` that does one thing, it makes little sense.

That was the Java developers' rationale some twenty years ago when generics were added to Java. A lot has happened since then. If someone wrote an interface like `List` in today's world, an interface with upwards of 20 abstract methods, half of which have "this method may not be supported and might just throw `UnsupportedOperationException`" *built-in* to the contract, they'd rightly be laughed off the stage.

Today's world is one of small, tight interfaces. We follow the SOLID principles. An interface does one thing and does it well. If an interface defines more than two or three (non-defaulted, non-inherited) methods, we give pause and ask if we can make it more modular. And we try to design systems that are more immutable by design, to support scaling and concurrency. We have `record`s, or `data class`es or whatever your favorite language calls them, that are immutable by default.

So twenty years ago, the idea of a massive super-interface that does twenty things and that can be narrowed down dynamically via type projections seemed pretty cool. Today, it makes far more sense to specify the variance at the declaration site, since most interfaces are small and have a clear use case in mind.

The [`scala.collection.Seq`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html) trait defines three abstract, non-inherited methods (`apply`, `iterator`, and `length`), and all of those use the type argument covariantly, so `Seq` is defined with a covariant type. The [corresponding mutable trait](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Seq.html) adds one more method (`update`), which uses its type argument contravariantly, so it has an invariant argument.

In Scala, if you want to modify a sequence, you take a `scala.collection.mutable.Seq`. If you want to read, you take a `scala.collection.Seq`. And those interfaces are small enough and narrow enough in purpose that the fact that there are several of those doesn't affect the code quality (and the fact that traits and classes in Scala are cheap to write, compared to the boilerplate necessary in Java to make even a simple class).

Answer (score 2):

> In other words, does Java's way offer useful extra flexibility not found in Scala, or is it just a lot of repetitive unwieldy boilerplate?

Suppose that class `Foo` extends class `Parent` and is in turn extended by class `Child`.

Then, as you know, we can pass an instance of `ArrayList<Foo>` to a method that takes a `List<? extends Parent>`, or to a method that takes a `List<? super Child>`.

A reason that a method might take `List<? extends Parent>` is if it only reads from the list (it never writes to it), and can happily support any element that's an instance of `Parent` (because it doesn't need anything specific to `Foo` or another subtype).

A reason that a method might take `List<? super Child>` is if it only writes to the list (it never reads from it), and the elements that it writes are always instances of `Child` (so it doesn't care whether the list can accept arbitrary instance of `Foo` or another supertype).

That said, yes, it *is* a lot of repetitive unwieldy boilerplate! As a result, it's not uncommon to come across a method that *could* take a `List<? extends Parent>` or a `List<? super Child>` but instead just takes a `List<Parent>` or a `List<Child>` (respectively).

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on this but it can be argued that the use of wildcard capture syntax in Java's Function interface allows for more flexibility in expressing variance relationships compared to Scala's Function1 trait, where variance is inherent in the type. The wildcard capture syntax allows for variance to be declared specifically in the context of a method's parameter or return type, rather than being inherent to the type itself. However, it can also be seen as repetitive and unwieldy boilerplate. It depends on the perspective of the developer and their use case.