# From a type system perspective, In Scala 3, should variance affect extensional equality between types `F[T]` and `F[_ <: T]`?

Tags: scala, covariance, variance, scala-3, higher-kinded-types

This is both a question and a poll. Considering the following case:

```
  trait Mat[+T]

  implicitly[Mat[Product] =:= Mat[_ <: Product]]

/* Compiler error:
: Cannot prove that com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.VarianceToBoundedType.Mat[Product] =:= com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.VarianceToBoundedType.Mat[? <: Product].
*/
```

It is easy to prove extensionally that:

```
implicitly[Mat[Product] <:< Mat[_ <: Product]]
```

Even without the covariance decorator, As any instance of the former `m: Mat[Product]` can be easily proven to inhabit `Mat[? <: Product]`. But when covariance is introduced, the reverse should be also true. Unfortunately, both of the following statement failed:

```
  implicitly[Mat[_ <: Product] <:< Mat[Product]]

  implicitly[Mat[Product] =:= Mat[_ <: Product]]
```

Is this a problematic behaviour of the compiler, or I ignored some edge cases of instances that can inhabits `Mat[? <: Product]` but not `Mat[Product]`?

**UPDATE 1**: A derivative case looks like this:

```
      trait Mat_* {
        type TT
      }

      trait TGen {
        type T
        type Mat = Mat_* { type TT <: T }
      }

      object LessThanProductGen extends TGen {
        type T <: Product
      }

      object ProductGen extends TGen {
        final type T = Product
      }

      implicitly[ProductGen.Mat <:< LessThanProductGen.Mat]
      implicitly[ProductGen.Mat =:= LessThanProductGen.Mat]
```

In object `LessThanProductGen`, the final type T is also indeterministic, The extensional equality check described above should work equally well. But the compiler reported a similar error:

```
: Cannot prove that ProductGen.Mat <:< LessThanProductGen.Mat
: Cannot prove that ProductGen.Mat =:= LessThanProductGen.Mat
```

**UPDATE 2:** To avoid using `TGen.T` as a dependent type, but as a type bound, I broke it into 2 parts, apparently this solved the problem and get my desired behaviour:

```
      trait Mat_* {
        type TT
      }

      trait TGen {
        type T_^
        type T_v <: T_^
        type Mat = Mat_* { type TT <: T_^ }
        // should be { type TT >: T_v <: T_^ } for invariant case
      }

      object ProductGen extends TGen {
        override type T_^ = Product
        override type T_v = Product
      }

      object LessThanProductGen extends TGen {
        override type T_^ = Product
        override type T_v = Nothing
      }

      implicitly[ProductGen.Mat =:= LessThanProductGen.Mat]
```

Comment: `Product <:<  (_ <: Product)` but `(_ <: Product) =:= Product` unless you can prove that existential type `_ <: Product` describes exactly `Product`. If you read `_ <: Product` as "some product subtype" it should be obvious: Product is a supertype of some product subtype, some Product subtype doesn't have to be supertype of Product. Relation `<:<` ca be proven in one way but not the other, thus it cannot be considered `=:=`. And it translated to variance. In your Update 2 example you have stable identifiers where compiler see that type is `Product` on both sides.

Comment: actually existential type was dropped in Scala 3: https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/dropped-features/existential-types.html#:~:text=The%20reasons%20for%20dropping%20them%20are%3A%201%20Existential,the%20gain%20of%20having%20them%20is%20relatively%20minor.

Comment: ... so right now Mat[_ <: Product] is just a refined type, like Mat[_] in java

Comment: If you treat `_ <: Product` as refined `Product` point stand still - refinement is an instance of `Product` but product is not necessary an instance of refinement, just like with existential types.

Comment: I know, I'm only talking about `Mat[_ <: Product]` which is a refined type, `_ <: Product` is not a type at all in DOT or any of its extension (try assigning it to an alias, you'll see)